# php математические операции ключ => значение

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
[
   'anyKey1' => 'anyNumber1',
   'anyKey2' => 'anyNumber2',
   'anyKey3' => 'anyNumber3',
            ...
]
```

Возможно ли сложить все значения (числа) и получить общее число?

P.s. Ключи все разные...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ar = array("key1" => "1", "key2" => 2);
var_dump(array_sum($ar));
```

[Документация по **array_sum()**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-sum.php)

Comment: Спасибо, помечу, но при арифметических действиях использую bcmath (нужна точность, так как числа не целые)

Comment: @Алексей ну если нужна прям занебесная точность, то возможно что-то и можете использовать дополнительно, но у `array_sum` нормально с вычислениями) не будет такого: `0.2+0.1 = 0.6`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ar = array("key1" => "1", "key2" => 2);
$sum = 0;              
foreach( $ar as $key => $value ) {
    $sum +=  $value;
}

echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

т.к.

> но при арифметических действиях использую `bcmath`

то в дополнение к ответам

```
$data = [ .... ] ;
$result = array_reduce($data, 'bcadd', '0');
```